# How can I to add a RichTextBox on the Evolus Pencil form?

Tags: richtextbox, mockups, mockup-tool, evolus-pencil

I have to add a simple RichTextBox-control on the form of [Evolus Pencil](http://pencil.evolus.vn/).
i.e. "a big field for input" with a vertical scroll, in which is possible to insert a rich Text Formated-text, and all this will be correctly displayed on the mockup of the form.

Answer (score 0):

The *Common Shapes* stencil collection included with Pencil has a *Rich Text* element that allows you to enter multi-line rich text content from within Pencil. The *Sketchy GUI* and *Native UI* collections contain scrollbar elements that you can add to the page alongside the rich text element.

Allowing people to edit the text content or scroll with the scrollbar once the mockup has been exported is not possible with Pencil, as the exported content is just static images (or vector images if you export to svg or pdf).